# Laravel mail embedded image not showing for some people

Tags: laravel, image, email

I have a problem with Laravel mail image embedding or rather its combination with Outlook. I'm sending a mail containing embedded profile image of user who created certain activity. For some reason some people however don't see the image only big X icon:
[image]

- I have tried attaching the image to the mail
- The mail is coming from same domain
- I was able to see the image even when I sent testing mail to my personal gmail account
- My settings are the same as the person who is not able to see the image

EDIT:

- image tag: `<img class="img" src="cid:generated_id@swift.generated">`

Comment: Because the image probably only exists in your local & not on production :) Right click on the image and paste here what is the src for this img tag!

Comment: I have added the edit, however the if it were the case of image only existing on local and not on prod (which this image exist on both with the same name) then why would I be able to see them when I get the mail from production aswell.